# Permutations with limited repetition and various constraints

Tags: combinatorics, permutations

you have a string of 360 letters: 180 x 'A' and 180 x 'B'. I (hope I) understand that the number of ways this string can be permuted is $$\frac{360!}{180!180!} = \binom{360}{180}$$

What I have absolutely no clue about is how to calculate how this number changes if the following restrictions are both put into place.

- The numbers of 'switches' ('AB' or 'BA') should be as close to equal as possible to the number of repetitions ('AA' or 'BB'). That would mean either 180 switches and 179 repetitions or vice versa.
- The maximum number consecutive repetitions is 3 (thus AAAB would be valid, AAAAB not).

Thanks for any insights!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Let's consider groups of one to three consecutive identical letters as building blocks and denote the numbers of such groups by $a_1$, $a_2$, $a_3$ for the As and by $b_1$, $b_2$, $b_3$ for the Bs, and let's first consider strings beginning with A and ending in B (and thus $179$ switches and $180$ repetitions). Then we have the following constraints:

\begin{align}
a_1+2a_2+3a_3&=180\;,\\
b_1+2b_2+3b_3&=180\;,\\
a_1+a_2+a_3&=90\;,\\
b_1+b_2+b_3&=90\;,\\
\end{align}

with solution

\begin{align}
a_2&=90-2a_1\;,\\
b_2&=90-2b_1\;,\\
a_3&=a_1\;,\\
b_3&=b_1\;.
\end{align}

Thus the number of admissible arrangements of this form is

$$
\left(\sum_{k=0}^{45}\binom{90}{k,k,90-2k}\right)^2=448581910545737950775083699792561795907509^2\;.
$$

The same number of arrangements begins with B and ends in A. You can carry out a similar analysis to find the number of admissible arrangements that begin and end with the same letter (and thus have $180$ switches and $179$ repetitions).

Comment: thanks so much! So for arrangements beginning and ending in A the 3rd equation simply becomes a_1+a_2+a_3=91, right? If I may, I have a follow-up question. Given only the second constraint is in place (maximum of 3 identical letters in a row), how would one describe the random variables "number of repetitions" and "number of switches"?

Comment: @Mathäus: Yes, the equation is right. The solution for the $a_i$ is then $a_2=93-2a_1$ and $a_3=a_1-2$, so the summation for the $a$s is 

$$
\sum_{a_1=2}^{46}\binom{91}{a_1,93-2a_1,a_1-2}
$$

 (while the summation for the $b$s stays the same). In your second question, I'm not sure exactly what you mean by "how would one describe" -- describe in what sort of form for which purpose?

Comment: sorry for being nonsensical, I do not have a math background at all and thus express myself much too vague (for solving the equations WolframAlpha helps). By describe I meant the distribution of such a variable, especially the mean and the standard deviation. [I ask all this to better understand the restricted randomization of trial order in a "task switching" experiment in cognitive psychology]

Comment: @Mathäus: The mean and standard deviation of those variables can be calculated -- it's a straightforward calculation but a bit too long for a follow-up question in the comment thread -- if you post a separate question about that and post a link here, I'd provide an answer as soon as I get to it.

Comment: Thank you for indulging me. The new question is [here](http://math.stackexchange.com/q/1708500/324858).

Comment: @Mathäus: I realized it's not quite as straightforward as I at first thought :-) I'll do it as promised, but I might not get to it during the (European) day.

Comment: P.S.: I've verified this result using the code I wrote for [this answer](http://math.stackexchange.com/a/1710081).