# Permutation with constrained repetition: Distribution of random variable "number of pairs of identical elements"

Tags: combinatorics, probability-distributions, permutations

You have a string of 360 letters: 180 x 'A' and 180 x 'B'. The number of ways this string can be permuted is $$\frac{360!}{180!180!} = \binom{360}{180}.$$
Assume the permutation is constricted according to the following criterion:

- the maximum number consecutive repetitions is 3 (thus AAAB would be valid, AAAAB not)

How would one calculate the mean and standard deviation of the following variables:

- The number of 'switches' ('AB' or 'BA') in a random permutation
- The number of 'repetitions' ('AA' or 'BB') in a random permutation?

It would be useful to be able to calculate the probability for a given number of switches or repetitions.

Comment: See also http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1707860.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've done some work on this but I don't have the time right now to write it up properly. Since you mentioned in comments on your other question that you need this for practical purposes, I'll report my results for now and will add the theoretical work later when I get to it.

I'll only refer to the number of switches; the number of repetitions is simply the complement of that and thus has the same variance.

I'll denote the number of occurrences of each letter by $n$, so in your case $n=180$. For large $n$, the probability of a pair of adjacent letters being a switch is

$$
\frac{x^3}{2x^3-x^2+1}\approx0.61842
$$

with $x=\frac13\left(1+\sqrt[3]{19-3\sqrt{33}}+\sqrt[3]{19+3\sqrt{33}}\right)$, so the expected number of switches is

$$
\mu\approx0.61842(2n-1)\;.
$$

I haven't found a closed form for the variance; numerically it's approximately $0.13191$ per pair for large $n$, so

$$
\sigma^2\approx0.13191(2n-1)\;.
$$

[Here's Java code](https://gist.github.com/joriki/f186179d8719a9d759b5) that computes the exact values for given $n$; the result for $n=180$ is

\begin{align}
\mu&\approx221.91\approx0.61814(2n-1)\;,\\
\sigma^2&\approx47.681\approx0.13282(2n-1)\;,
\end{align}

in good agreement with the values for large $n$.

The code computes the entire probability distribution for the number of switches; here are the values where the probability is greater than $10^{-3}$:

```
203 : 0.0012388217032911677
204 : 0.0018412203267515936
205 : 0.002736545769772046
206 : 0.003878324197447609
207 : 0.005496490775581141
208 : 0.007434408770860175
209 : 0.010055585650718934
210 : 0.01299090718927192
211 : 0.016783077133673555
212 : 0.020725473597705827
213 : 0.025593951122786774
214 : 0.03023289798299867
215 : 0.03571266179517819
216 : 0.04037973053903922
217 : 0.04565670987385107
218 : 0.04944417851097123
219 : 0.053545837958528755
220 : 0.05557232965938595
221 : 0.057675515810647
222 : 0.05739616780630198
223 : 0.05711817280775909
224 : 0.054531121956119324
225 : 0.05206124628323564
226 : 0.04770548259302429
227 : 0.043714148851757
228 : 0.038463569043319164
229 : 0.03384364519065129
230 : 0.028605833916204415
231 : 0.024178652430368527
232 : 0.01963911905769061
233 : 0.015951881457120055
234 : 0.01245557012913083
235 : 0.009725575485169464
236 : 0.007302396335265708
237 : 0.00548296523106703
238 : 0.003959936175572079
239 : 0.0028599660683153293
240 : 0.001987322246410523
241 : 0.0013809428562222776
```

The mode is $221$, and the median is $223$, both close to the mean. Here's a plot:

[image: plot of the distribution]

Comment: Really interesting! Would it be possible/worthwile (and/or warranting a new question) to design a function that takes as inputs the total number of letters (360 in this example); the number of allowed consecutive identical letters (3 here); and the ratio switches:repetitions (was 180:179 in my [other question](http://math.stackexchange.com/q/1707860/324858))?

Comment: @Mathäus: You described the input of the desried function but not its output :-) I guess it should output the number of admissible strings with the given parameters? Do you mean a function in a program or a mathematical function? The Java code I posted could easily be modified to provide such a function.

Comment: oh, sorry, the output such an algorithm/program would be a random valid permutation of the whole sequence.

Comment: @Mathäus: That sounds like a difficult problem on the face of it, but I'll give it a thought. I'm assuming that by "random" you mean uniformly randomly drawn from all valid permutations.

Comment: exactly. I guess that would be a very specific and strange thing to ask of an algorithm, so don't bother if it isn't feasible. thanks.

Comment: @Mathäus: I think it should be possible to do this without the restriction to a fixed number of switches; but if you want $180$ switches, that doesn't help, since the probability for that is about $7\cdot10^{-11}$, so you can't just produce strings until one of them happens to have $180$ switches. I'll give it some more thought.

Comment: @Mathäus: How important is it that the distribution is exactly uniform? Would it help to have something that produces strings that look random to the naked eye but aren't exactly uniformly drawn from all valid strings?

Comment: that would not be very important as long as a lot of valid combinations can be produced. what you described before (producing strings until they satisfy the constrains) is what is commonly done in the case of generating trial orders in the task switching experiment. as you said, that takes a lot of processing power.

Comment: @Mathäus: I'm thinking that perhaps the entire mathematical focus on reproducing a particular distribution was a bit misplaced, and you could do something a lot simpler: The whole thing can be described as a process of stringing together runs of $1$, $2$ or $3$ identical letters with certain probabilities, which add up to $1$, so there are two degrees of freedom. Fixing the expected number of switches removes one degree of freedom; so there's only one left. You could think about whether there's some further property that you'd like to optimize using that degree of freedom.

Comment: @Mathäus: Or you could fix it arbitrarily. In either case, you'd then have a very simple process: building strings by independently choosing runs of $1$, $2$ or $3$ identical letters according to the probabilities determined; and repeating until you get a string with the desired number of switches. Since the expected number of switches is now the desired number, you don't have to produce nearly as many strings as for the uniform distribution.

Comment: that doesn't sound too hard, thank you! If I run into unexpected issues, I will post another question.

Comment: @Mathäus: OK -- and feel free to post a link here so I get notified.